# Open all files in directory to test conditions

Tags: python, pandas, directory, iteration

I want to iterate through files in a directory and test each of them to see if they meet my selection criteria. Python is finding my file, and then immediately claiming to have not found my file. I am not sure what is going on.

```
import pandas as pd
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print('file %s located' %file)
        in_file=pd.read_csv(file)
```

The error goes as follows:

```
runfile('F:/School/Research/WGM/NewProject/PythonScripts/EqiSiteSorter.py', wdir='F:/School/Research/WGM/NewProject/PythonScripts')
file FileName.csv located
Traceback (most recent call last):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'FileName.csv' does not exist: b'FileName.csv'
```

It successfully prints the message which states that the file was located, the file name is stored as a string in my variables, but apparently it suddenly got lost after that. Help please...

Comment: As explained in the [os.walk documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), `dirs` and `files` in your example will be relative to `subdir` - so you should do sth. like `os.path.join(subdir, file)` to get the correct path to each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks because of the directories. Inside the read calc try suing os.path.join(dir,filename)

This should work.